# Python else statement

Tags: python-3.x

During the for loop, if there are no results, I don't received the printed output 'No matches', as condition would be False if there are no matching records, correct?

```
import csv, sys

#command line arguments converting to variables
first_csv = sys.argv[1]
second_csv = sys.argv[2]


#add items in first list 
with open(first_csv, 'r') as first:
    reader_one = csv.reader(first)
    x = list(reader_one)

#add items in the second list
with open(second_csv, 'r') as second:
    reader_two = csv.reader(second)
    y = list(reader_two)

#comparing IPs in both lists then outputting matches to text file
def compare_lists():
    txt_file = open('results.txt', 'w+')
    for IPs in x:
        if IPs in y:
            z = IPs[0] #removed list brackets
            txt_file.write('\n') #creating new line
            txt_file.write(str(z))
        else: 
            txt_file.write('No matches')
    txt_file.close()

compare_lists()
```

Comment: Are you sure that `x` is populated with at least one value when you run the loop?

Comment: Yeah, utilizing test data currently before rolling into production

Comment: Just put a print statement directly inside of the loop. Right before the `if IPs in y:`, put like `print("here")` or something. You have to see if the loop is even being entered. I ran that exact code with test data (`x = [1], y =[5]`) to check the else statement and it worked fine for me...

Comment: Should there be a match? if yes, is IPs[0] a white-space?